# What's the method to access whatever child item is displayed in an Android spinner, instead of just waiting for an onItemSelected() event?

Tags: java, android

As the title says, what is the method to access which item is displayed in an Android spinner, so I can have multiple spinners, then wait on a button click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spinner.getSelectedItem() to get the currently selected spinner item:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem

Comment: Or `getSelectedItemId()`, `getSelectedItemPosition()`, and `getSelectedView()`. This works for every subclass of `AdapterView` (e.g., `ListView`).